# Unable to run Robot Framework tests in headless mode from Linux server - WebDriverException

Tags: linux, selenium, robotframework, headless, selenium2library

We are trying to run Robot framework tests on a Linux server in headless mode.  When run Robot tests, we are getting error :WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Devtools port number file contents <35674> were in an unexpected format.

The chromedriver path setup correctly in the Robot test.Curl command is successful with chromedriver 2.30 and chrome 60.0 versions on this Linux server.So it could be something that we are missing in Robot configuration that's causing this issue.

Tested with both combinations and the result is same:

Robot Framework-Selenium2Library v3.0, Chrome version : 60.0.3112.90,  Chromer driver version: 2.30.477691

Robot Framework-Selenium2Library v3.0, Chrome version : 73.0.3683.20 ,  Chromer driver version: 2.46

```
*** Settings ***
Library           Selenium2Library
Library           OperatingSystem

*** Variables ***
${url}            https://www.google.com/


*** Test Cases ***
Simple UI Login

Log     Creating WebDriver   WARN
${chrome_options}=  Evaluate  sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()  sys,selenium.webdriver
${ws}=    Set Variable    window-size=1920,1080
Call Method   ${chrome_options}   add_argument     test-type
Call Method   ${chrome_options}   add_argument     --no-sandbox
Call Method   ${chrome_options}   add_argument     --disable-setuid-sandbox
Call Method   ${chrome_options}   add_argument    --headless
Call Method   ${chrome_options}    add_argument    ${ws}
Call Method   ${chrome_options}   add_argument     --disable-gpu
${options}=  Call Method   ${chrome_options}    to_capabilities
Create WebDriver   Chrome   executable_path=/opt/chromedriver/2.30/chromedriver
desired_capabilities=${options}
Go To   ${url}
```

Expected :  Test runs successfully in headless mode.

Actual :   OTC[001] : Simple UI login :: Sample test case to demonstrate simp... | FAIL |
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477691 (6ee44a7247c639c0703f291d320bdf05c1531b57),platform=Linux 3.10.0-862.14.4.el7.x86_64 x86_64)

Comment: Can you use latest SeleniumLib 3.3.1, in that you can simply choose Headless Chrome when using the Open Browser keyword.

Comment: If you can manage bringing all components to their latest versions: Robot Framework, Selenium Library, Selenium, ChromeDriver and Chrome.

Comment: The argument `test-type` stands out for me - it is defined as ['Type of the current test harness ("browser" or "ui")'](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/content/public/common/content_switches.cc?q=kTestType&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=801), yet - you aren't giving any of the two values; nor it is prefixed with the "--"? I must admit, I haven't seen or used it before, shooting in the dark here.

Comment: Tested with SeleniumLib 3.3.1 version, Selenium2Library 3.0.0, Chrome  73.0.3683.20 , Chromer driver version: 2.46. I get this error :  OTC[001] : Simple UI login :: Sample test case to demonstrate simp... | FAIL |
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Devtools port number file contents <35674> were in an unexpected format
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.46.628388 (4a34a70827ac54148e092aafb70504c4ea7ae926),platform=Linux 3.10.0-862.14.4.el7.x86_64 x86_64)

Comment: Todor- adding or removing that option has no change either. BTW, `--test-type` is basically the 2014 version of `--enable-automation`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you have tried with SeleniumLibrary 3.3.1 so here is what I have used to run tests on a Linux server in headless mode. These are the different versions I have installed:

- Chrome Version 72.0.3626.96
- ChromeDriver 72.0.3626.69 (3c16f8a135abc0d4da2dff33804db79b849a7c38)
- robotframework==3.1.1
- robotframework-seleniumlibrary==3.3.1
- selenium==3.141.0

From SeleniumLibrary 3.1.0, with Selenium 3.8.0 or newer the [`Open Browser`](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Open%20Browser) supports  Headless Firefox and Headless Chrome. This means that you can use headless mode without any additional webdriver configuration.

```pyhon
*** Settings ***
Library     SeleniumLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
Headless Browser Test
    [Setup]    Open Browser    https://stackoverflow.com    Headless Chrome
    Maximize Browser Window

    Title Should Be    Stack Overflow - Where Developers Learn, Share, & Build Careers

    [Teardown]    Close Browser
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a working example you can use that checks the title of google.com.

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation
...    Basic Test for Google.com in headless mode

Library    Collections
Library    DateTime
Library    Dialogs
Library    OperatingSystem
Library    SeleniumLibrary
Library    String
Library    RequestsLibrary

Suite Setup    Setup Environment and Open Browser
Suite Teardown    Close All Browsers

*** Variables ***
${BROWSER}      HeadlessChrome
${SITE_URL}     https://www.google.com

*** Test Cases ***

Title Test
    Title Should Be    Google

*** Keywords ***
Open Chrome Browser To URL
    [Documentation]    Open Chrome browser and navigate to URL with browser options set
    [Tags]  open_chrome_browser
    ${browserOptions}    Run Keyword If    'Headless' in '${BROWSER}'    Set Headless Chrome Options
    Create Webdriver    Chrome    chrome_options=${browserOptions}
    Go To    ${SITE_URL}
    Maximize Browser Window

Browser timeout and speed
    [Documentation]
    ...    Set browser timeout and speed
    Set Selenium Timeout   30s
    Set Selenium Speed   0s

Set Headless Chrome Options
    [Documentation]
    ...     Set the Chrome options for running in headless mode.  Restrictions do not apply to headless mode.
    [Tags]   headless_chrome_options
    ${chromeOptions}    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys
    Call Method    ${chromeOptions}    add_argument    test-type
    Call Method    ${chromeOptions}    add_argument    --headless
    Call Method    ${chromeOptions}    add_argument    --disable-extensions
    Call Method    ${chromeOptions}    add_argument    --disable-gpu
    Call Method    ${chromeOptions}    add_argument    --disable-dev-shm-usage
    Call Method    ${chromeOptions}    add_argument    --no-sandbox
    [Return]  ${chromeOptions}

Setup Environment and Open Browser
    [Documentation]
    ...    This keyword will establish the environment variables and open a browser
    [Tags]    simple_test

    Open Chrome Browser To URL
    Browser timeout and speed
'''
```